# What is the meaning of this statement in EGA I (2.2.4)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

This is a statement made in EGA I (2.2.4)

"Tout espace noetherien est quasi-compact;inversement, tout espace topologique dans lequel tout ouvert est quasi-compact est noetherien."

The first statement is clear from ascending chain property of open sets. However, I do not get the 2nd statement.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is the second statement saying that if $X$ is a topological space s.t. any $U\subset X$ open is quasi compact, then $X$ is noetherian? This does not look obvious at all and it looks very strange. If $X$ has finite covering property and $X$ is locally noetherian, then it follows easily that $X$ is noetherian. Finite covering property is guaranteed by all open sets compact. However, $X$ local noetherian property is left out here. What is the translation of the 2nd statement? Have I misunderstood the statement?

In other words, I can conclude that $X$ is noetherian iff $X$ is locally noetherian and $X$ is quasi-compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a community translation project for EGA at https://github.com/ryankeleti/ega they translate your sentence as "(2.2.4). Any Noetherian space is quasi-compact; conversely, any topological space in which all open sets are quasi-compact
is Noetherian." so it sounds like you have the right translation. And there are some remarks on the proof at this question [Are there non-noetherian topological spaces in which every open subset is quasi-compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/are-there-non-noetherian-topological-spaces-in-which-every-open-subset-is-quasi?rq=1)

Comment: Ah. Sure the post in stack exchange does answer it clearly. It is noetherian. I was wondering why it is the case as I had different characterization in mind. Thanks for the link to translation.